Ubuntu server freezes after unplugging the USB keyboard
I've Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS server edition.
It is installed on a Mini PC from Teclast, and everything works fine while the USB keyboard is connected, once I unplug it the system freezes, sometimes also I start the PC without it, and SSH remotely, this works for a few minutes then the server freezes, if I keep the keyboard on, it will keep working as if nothing is there!
Here are some logs found while digging online, and I've tried many proposed solutions, such as checking BIOS settings, Changing Grup default boot settings, etc ... none worked for me
[    0.775394] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.UBTC.RUCC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/psargs-330)
[    0.775410] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS01._PLD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230628/psparse-529)
[    0.775963] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.UBTC.RUCC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/psargs-330)
[    0.775988] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS01._PLD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230628/psparse-529)
[    0.776020] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.UBTC.RUCC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/psargs-330)
[    0.776030] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS02._PLD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230628/psparse-529)
[    0.776048] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.UBTC.RUCC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/psargs-330)
[    0.776057] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS02._PLD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230628/psparse-529)
[    1.145513] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.UBTC.RUCC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/psargs-330)
[    1.145547] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS02._PLD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230628/psparse-529)
[    1.146612] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.UBTC.RUCC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/psargs-330)
[    1.146645] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS02._PLD due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230628/psparse-529)
[    5.269846] ACPI: video: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)


Thank you, @guiverc. I've changed the tag, and no, I didn't install any desktop or desktop packages; it is as mentioned exactly in the issue description.

Not a real solution - but why don't you connect with ssh to your server? The errors rather indicate that your BIOS is crippled (ACPI - the interface to the hardware of your device)... I wouldn't use it as a server - not reliable.

@kanehekili I'm connected via SSH, as long as the keyboard is attached, everything working just fine, once I remove it, my SSH session stops, and the server freezes.

Did you try upgrading the kernel version?
